# Power BI slicer based on date

Tags: powerbi

I am struggling to manage to set up a slicer in Power BI on date column.

The problem I have is that I have a table with SalesDate so I created a table with client name and date of last sale.

Then I added a slicer on date column and here I am stuck.

I would like to be able to mark date into a slicer so the table returned me all the customers who DID NOT buy anything from a specific amount of time: last three months for example.
By default slicer shows me those transactions who did happen in the period I provide to a slicer.

Can I do it in anyway?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Are you using a star schema? Can you provide a .pbix?

Comment: There is only one table in the data model so no need to use a star schema. The data in the model is sensitive and I cannot attach the .pbix unfourtunately :(

Comment: I'm afraid PBI always needs a star schema if you don't want to run into problems like auto exists. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-dax-auto-exist/